# Fantasy Premier League API

Tags: api

Does anyone know if there is an API for the fantasy Premier league website? Found a few old posts but the links don't work anymore. There are a couple of apps on the app store so must be something ?

Answer (score 88):

**EDIT**

The below still works for the 2022/2023 season.

It seems for the 2019/2020 season, they renamed the URLs from `drf` to `api`. Here are the new URLS:

All player/team data and more:

- https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/
- Specific player: [https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/[player_id]/](https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/%5Bplayer_id%5D/)
- Example first player: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/1/

**ORIGINAL**

These are new ones that currently work:

- All player/team data and more: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static
- Specific player: [https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/element-summary/[player_id]](https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/element-summary/%5Bplayer_id%5D)
- Example Ospina: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/element-summary/1

**EDIT**:
To find out about the links, you can check the APIs called by the fpl website client.
On Chrome, go to view -> developer -> developer tools. Then click on the network tab. After that, click on a player info in your team, and check the call that is being made on the network tab (see pic below).

[image]

**EDIT 2**: You can see an example of implementation in Python here where you get interesting statistics about a certain league. You can use it as a starting point. https://github.com/spinach/FantasyPremierLeague-Api_Python

Comment: Why isn't this the answer over the pointless 'Yup it's gone!' comment above?

Comment: Are there any APIs to get data on teams rather than players?

Comment: @AndyW You can always use the `All player data` link and filter by the team Id that you're interested in. Not sure if there is an easier way as of today

Comment: That would just give me the data of players in a team. I'm after data of the teams themselves (e.g team name)

Comment: @AndyW Check the `teams` object in the json of the first link. You get an array of team id, team name etc.

Comment: You are right! I had not seen that amongst all the data. Perhaps change your answer to say the link has more than just "All player data" since the question is not specifically about player data.

Comment: @AndyW aha you're right, I will update the answer, thanks :)

Comment: How do you know which player has got what id? i.e id Ospina has id 1 then how do I know De Gea has what id?

Comment: @sphoenix The json offers a mapping (in the array "elements") between players <-> id so you just have to use that mapping

Comment: they have stopped this. Is there any alternate?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha it seems they renamed the url. Instead of `drf`, they changed it to `api`. I updated my answer

Comment: @Guy Daher I get the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output/allPlayersInfo.json'` when following the instructions. Do you know what the issue might be? I am running your league script.