# Python Web Scraping with lxml

Tags: python, lxml, scrape

I am trying to scrape column names (player, cost, sel., form, pts) from the page below:

https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/statistics/total_points

However, I am failing to do so. Let me show you what I have done:

```
from lxml import html
import requests


page = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/statistics/total_points'
#Take site and structure html
page = requests.get(page)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#Using the page's CSS classes, extract all links pointing to a team
Location = tree.cssselect('.ism-thead-bold tr .ism-table--el-stats__name')
```

When I do this, Location should be a list that contains a string "Player". However, it returns an empty list which means cssselect did not capture anything.

Though each column name has a different 'th class', I used one of them (ism-table--el-stats__name) for this specific trial just to make it simple.

When this problem is fixed, I want to use regex since every class has different suffix after two underscores.

Comment: There are no such elements in the actual HTML source. Presumably, like most complex data-driven websites, this content is built from some API. I just did a quick google search and this SO post may be helpful (although it is 2 years old so may no longer be correct): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663726/fantasy-premier-league-api

Comment: I checked it already. This does not work. Thank you tho

Comment: What does not work?  Are you saying you actually tried to use their API?   The key point is that page you fetch with `requests.get` doesn't have of the information you want, because the page you SEE is build on the fly using Javascript.  You will have to use something like Selenium to run a real browser to run the Javascript.

Comment: A good trick to scraping pages is to turn off JavaScript and refresh the page. If you can no longer see the data then you'll need to work out where it comes from (it will likely be populated by JavaScript).